# QGIS export to DXF crash

Tags: qgis, export, dxf

[image]

I have a point GPKG layer with 14 features. It has a number of symbol styles. I click import/export -> export project to DXF -> select only this point layer. It exports in a split second.

I have a polygon GPKG layer with 2 features. It has a number of symbol styles. I click import/export -> export project to DXF -> select only this polygon layer. QGIS goes to not responding.

What am I doing wrong or misunderstanding here?

Comment: Probably impossible to say without test data and even then it may be too hard for anybody who is not a QGIS developer. Conversions between CAD and GIS tend to be difficult. Can you export polygons with simple styles?

Comment: Yes. And with multiple styles. I’ve checked the geometry is “valid”. I’ve copied the exact styles to another GPKG. Short of reconstructing the fields, which I can’t see how they can make a difference